# Is there a single word for "reducing various arguments of different levels to the same level"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A man faces various arguments, of different sophistication, consistency and factual accuracy, on a particular matter. Due to him unable to perceive and analyze them, or he just doesn't care, or he's misinterpreting what "critical thinking" actually is, he decides that all the arguments are at the same level, and say "Well, so people don't have a consensus on this matter, which means there's no truth!", and dismiss the more credible ones as "authorities means nothing" as when people refer to it.

Is there a single word to describe such act, or way of thinking?

Comment: Fox News Viewer.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I don't think it's a reference many people knows.

Comment: Sorry. It's apt in the US though. Fox specializes in exactly this kind of specious logic, calling it "fair and balanced" as long as they can find one lackey to support their talking points against the overwhelming facts.

Comment: Hmm, it's still a interesting fact to know, though.

Comment: "Never argue with an idiot. They will only bring you down to their level and beat you with experience." -
George Carlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two words maybe [false equivalence](http://www.skepticalraptor.com/skepticalraptorblog.php/logical-fallacies/false-equivalence-logical-fallacies/%22false%20equivalence%22) fits.

> **false equivalence**:  a logical fallacy where there appears to be a logical equivalence (usually in quantity and quality of evidence) between two opposing arguments, but when in fact there is one side has substantially higher quality and quantity of evidence.
>    *[- skepticalraptor](http://www.skepticalraptor.com/skepticalraptorblog.php/logical-fallacies/false-equivalence-logical-fallacies/%22false%20equivalence%22)*

Comment: Thanks, this is a good word for describing the behaviour I want to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are a variety of *logical fallacies* that people fall prey to, which prevent them from sorting out good arguments from empty bloviating. So there is really no one word, other than **gullible**.

The logical fallacies are too numerous to describe here, but here is a link to a list.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies

Most politicians, and certain "news" outlets, intentionally exploit these fallacies to mislead and deceive their respective audiences.

Comment: Reading that list of fallacies made me think about playing buzzword bingo again in my next meeting

Answer (score 0):

A man receives conflicting arguments from different sources.  The author
says the quality of these sources vary and that this quality may be discerned
by the man. (At least he implies the man is aware of credentials.)

What the man does...

The man dismisses the authorities and concludes there is no truth because there is no consensus.

Is there a single word to describe such thing?  Describe what?

The man makes the decision to consider all arguments equally without considering quality because he doesn't care.  Word?

The man makes the decision to consider all arguments equally without considering quality because he's misinterpreting "critical thinking".  Word.  (This is the logic
version of the question that seems to have been addressed already)

The man makes the decision to consider all arguments equally without considering quality because he cannot perceive or analyze them.  Word?

(... and implied I think)
The man makes the decision to consider all arguments equally without considering quality (as it relates to credential) because of contempt for authority.  Word?

Beyond the author's question of the man treatment of the arguments (which I admit I may 
have wrong) there's this very interesting sub one:

The man assumes consensus relates to truth.   Word?